# Chrome using a lot of battery without being open

Tags: battery, battery-life, chrome-for-android

I got a new phone (pixel 4a) and chrome is using a lot of battery without being open. If I pause the app I get much longer battery life. When checking my battery usage by app chrome is always the number one.

For example, over about 8 hours it used 25% of my battery but was only open for 7 minutes.

Is there anything I can do besides pausing the app constantly to fix the battery usage? Should I just suck it up and hope an update fixes this?

[image: picture of chrome using 25% battery with 7 minutes of usage]

Comment: May I know if you're browsing some sites with heavy processing, like YouTube (or video streaming in general) or browser games, for example?

Comment: I'm not, I only open it for random small things I google and then close it shortly after.  I usually don't even open the full app but just use the embedded single tab version.